# WSO2 Business Process Deployment + Rule Service Error

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-business-process

Good day, I am trying to deploy a basic number division business process on a WSO2 BPS 3.5.0 server, that employs a simple rule service to determine if the divisor is 0. The issue fires when I try to invoke the rule service which runs on a WSO2 BRS 2.2.0 server.

The error is:

```
org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: Cannot find WSDL definition for invoke service {http://test.org/rule}canDivide. Required resources not found in the BPEL package DivideNumbersBP-1.0.0-20.
```

When I add the `.wsdl` file to the BPS root project and use it from there, the application deploys and runs without any problems at all. Is there any way to avoid doing this?

Update: I found what was causing the problem but I am currently unable to solve it, into the import tag I am using a link like so: `<address>/<service>?wsdl` but the BPS changes it automatically to `<address>/<service>.wsdl` which is a resource that doesn't exist. Should I just package the `wsdl` file inside the BPS project, is this a common practice?

PS: This is my first question on this site so any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the wsdl in the BPS project, else it would not know the service description.

Why would you want to not include the wsdl in BPS project?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what I don't want is to include the wsdl file itself into the project. I want the BPS project to get the wsdl file from the  BRS http endpoint so I don't have to repackage the BPS project if the wsdl file gets a modification. Should I edit my question?